Здравствуйте, делаю игру и вылезла ошибка: AttributeError: 'Enemy' object has no attribute 'move'
import pygame
pygame.init()
display_w = 800
display_h = 600
display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_w, display_h))
pygame.display.set_caption('Run in Live')
logo = pygame.image.load('Run.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(logo)
make_jump = False
make_up = False
dy = 20
dy2 = 10
dy3 = 10


class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, speed):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.speed = speed


def move(self):
    if self.x >= -self.width:
        pygame.draw.rect(display, (150, 20, 200), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        self.x -= self.speed
    else:
        self.x = display_w + 50
        
def create_enemies(enemies):
    enemies.append(Enemy(display_w + 50, display_h - 170, 20, 70, 4))
    enemies.append(Enemy(display_w + 50, display_h - 170, 300, 600, 4))
    enemies.append(Enemy(display_w + 50, display_h - 170, 200, 500, 4))

enemy_width = 20
enemy_height = 70
enemy_x = display_w - 50
enemy_y = display_h - enemy_height - 100


pers_width = 60
pers_height = 100
pers_x = display_w // 4
pers_y = display_h - 100 - pers_height

def rungame():
    global make_jump, make_up
    game = True
    enemies = []
    create_enemies(enemies)
    while game:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            make_jump = True
        if make_jump:
            jump()
        keys2 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys2[pygame.K_UP]:
            make_up = True
        if make_up:
            up()
       
        display.fill((242, 243, 187))
        draw_enemies(enemies)
        pygame.draw.rect(display, (251, 186, 0), (pers_x, pers_y, pers_width, pers_height))
        pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 128, 0), (enemy_x, enemy_y, enemy_width, enemy_height))
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)
def jump():
    global make_jump, pers_y, dy
    if dy >= -20:
        pers_y -= dy
        dy -= 1
    else:
        dy = 20
        make_jump = False
def up():
    global make_up, pers_height, dy2
    if dy2 >= -10:
        pers_height -= dy2
        dy2 -= 1
    else:
        dy2 = 10
        make_up = False
def draw_enemies(enemies):
    for x in enemies:
        x.move()
rungame()


Вероятно, проблема с отступами при определении функций в классе.

Функция move должна быть внутри класса enemy.

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, speed):
       ...

def move(self):
    ...

В Питоне табуляции архи важны. Ваш метод move "выпал" из класса Enemy и стал самостоятельной функцией, не привязанной к классу. Правильно так:
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, speed):
        ...

    def move(self):
        ...

